# Interview - Array of Integers A with a size N, with indexes 0 <= P <= Q < N, write a function to find maximum of (A[Q] + A[P] + Q-P)

Tags: algorithm

I received this interview question, but I wasn't sure how to solve it:

You're given an array of integers A with a size N. For the indexes 0 <= P <= Q < N, write a function that finds the maximum of (A[Q] + A[P] + Q-P).
Expected time complexity is O(N) and O(1) space.

What would be the solution in Java?
(updated with Iraklius solution)

```
int[] a = new int[] {3,5,2,1,2};
int max_q=a[a.length-1];
int result = 0;
for(int q=a.length-2; q>=0; q--) {
    result = Math.max(result, max_q + a[p]-p);
    max_q = Math.max(max_q,a[q]+q);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you want to maximize `A[Q] + Q` and `A[P] - P`.

Comment: So there is a simple solution, by calculating all possible (A[Q] + A[P] + Q-P) values, and find the maximum... but this will be O(N^2) and not O(N). Edit : the previous comment seems a interesting approach. Find maximum/ min of both expression separately will be O(N) each, and 2*O(N) is still O(N)

Comment: Yes, makes more sense :)

Comment: since the expression is A[Q] + Q - (P - A[P]), you want max of A[Q]-Q and min of P-A[P], so max of A[P]-P

Comment: Seems great, if I would write the algorithm in Java how could I show the interviewers in a notepad? creating a method passing the array as a parameter and returning a Integer?

Comment: ...This isn't a take-home interview, is it?

Comment: Nope, I had to do it on a whiteboard, I tried to explain how to do it, but I couldn't write it on the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the right end of the array and maintain a variable let's call `max_q` which will be maximum of `A[Q] + Q` values you've considered. Initially `max_q = A[N - 1]` and the update rule is `max_q = max(max_q, A[i] + i)`. Now consider that you pick `i-th` element as your `P`, so the answer will be `result = max(result, max_q + A[i] - i)`. You should update `result` first and then update `max_q`.

Comment: I updated the question with the code, is it correct?

Comment: No, that's `O(N^2)` solution, get rid of second `for`, start first with `q = a.length - 2`. Then at first update `result`, then update `max_q`.

Comment: how do I get the 'p' value?